# Parallel processing of JMS messages?

Tags: jboss, jms

Is it possible to create a pool of Message Listeners or a Message Driven Beans to process messages from a JMS queue or topic in parallel ?

I am using JBoss and JBoss's JMS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if the MDB pool size is greater than one, JBoss should create multiple MDBs to process the messages in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely.  I've done it with JMS queues to create a multi-server pool of listeners in order to process large numbers of transactions.  You can use the Competing Consumers pattern.  I used a modified one, since we needed to process messages in order within accounts.  We used a lease mechanism to allocate servers to account number ranges, providing failover and scalability.

We were using Tibco's JMS provider, but it works with any JMS provider.